# Cheese isn't working from the Software Centre

Tags: 12.04, software-center, webcam, cheese

I've been trying to use Cheese, but the current version from the Ubuntu Software Centre doesn't seem to work at all. It just opens and then closes. I downloaded the latest stable version from the website, but I don't have the slightest idea on how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing cheese from terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

I tried it and it worked for me... I am running 13.04.

Good Luck